# Checking if Map is ordered by Value

Tags: scala

I'm trying to check if a Map[Int, Long] is in the correct sequence. Basically, each key in the map represents the order of which the event is supposed to occur and the value is a timestamp (epoch milli).

- When the key == 1 this means the first event and then the corresponding timestamp.
- When the key == 2 this means the second event and then the corresponding timestamp. Timestamp should be greater than the timestamp at 1.
- When the key == 3 this means the third event and then the corresponding timestamp. Timestamp should be greater than the timestamp at 2.
- etc.

In sequence Map (good: true):

```scala
Map(1 -> 1558324800000, 2 -> 1558497600000, 3 -> 1558584000000, 5 -> 1559188800000)
```

Out of sequence Map (bad: false -- event 5 is out of sequence):

```scala
Map(1 -> 1558324800000, 2 -> 1558497600000, 3 -> 1558584000000, 4 -> 1559016000000, 5 -> 1558497600000)
```

I basically want to sort by the key (some keys can be missing which is okay as long as the values are in ascending order) and then check if the timestamp values are in ascending order. I'm a bit stuck on how to implement this check.

Comment: **Maps** are unordered collections by design. You can order then by `Key` but not for `Value`. I would suggest using a **List** of pairs instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez They aren't _necessarily_ ordered, but `SortedMap`s are still `Map`s.

Comment: @AlexyRomanov Yeah, that is why I said you can order them by key. I should have been explicit about that being a `SortedMap`. But if you have a `Map` you do not have any guarantee that it will be sorted.

Answer (score 4):

No reason to sort it twice...

```
m.size <= 1 ||
m.toList.sortBy(_._1).sliding(2).forall{ case List((_, a), (_, b)) => a <= b }
```

Comment: Don't need `sortBy()`, `.sorted` works. Throws if `m` has only one element.

Comment: @jwvh I'd assume that it will implicitly construct lexicographical ordering on tuples, which would take both components of the tuple into account, and moreover, it would add some additional control flow branches after the first comparison: it should check whether the first comparison gave you a `0`, and if this was the case, it would proceed with the comparison of the second component. Lexicographical order is not really needed in this case. I don't know, maybe branch prediction eliminates this overhead...

Comment: @jwvh Oh, indeed, it throws for Maps with one element. That's weird. Added `size <= 1` check. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why `sliding(n)` does what it does when `0 < n < size`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach: convert the `Map` to a sorted List of Tuples and do a `sliding(2)` to check whether the adjacent values are in the right ordering:

```
val m1 = Map(1 -> 1558324800000L, 2 -> 1558497600000L, 3 -> 1558584000000L, 5 -> 1559188800000L)
val m2 = Map(1 -> 1558324800000L, 2 -> 1558497600000L, 3 -> 1558584000000L, 4 -> 1559016000000L, 5 -> 1558497600000L)

def checkKVOrdered(m: Map[Int, Long]): Boolean =
  m.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).sliding(2).forall{ case Seq(a, b) => a <= b }

checkKVOrdered(m1)
// res1: Boolean = true

checkKVOrdered(m2)
// res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: That was my original idea too. Then I found out that `m.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).sliding(2).forall{ case List(a, b) => a <= b }`  `m.toList.sortBy(_._1).sliding(2).forall{ case List((_, a), (_, b)) => a <= b }` have exactly the same length, surprisingly enough, so one `map`-step can be omitted.

Comment: Well, if you want smaller length, write it as `case Seq(a, b) => a._2 <= b._2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
def isOrderedByValue(m: Map[Int, Long]): Boolean = {
  val l = m.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
  l == l.sorted
}
```

or if heeding Luis's advice try

```
def isOrderedByValue(m: List[(Int, Long)]): Boolean = {
  val l = m.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
  l == l.sorted
}
```

This solution sorts twice though, which is not necessary as shown by other answers.

Comment: Seems very easy to understand, but may be it is no fastest solution

Answer (score 2):

Note: if you construct a [`SortedMap[Int, Long]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/SortedMap.html) instead of `Map[Int, Long]`, you'll get iteration in order of keys for free (the trade-off is that each insertion will take longer). In that case,

```
val map: SortedMap[Int, Long] = ...
val isOrdered = map.size <= 1 || map.sliding(2).forall { m => m.head._2 <= m.last._2 }
```

should work. See also [`IntMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/IntMap.html) (which gives the standard order for non-negative keys).